# Node link diagram in R using Rpart.plot and rattle

Tags: r, rpart, tidymodels, rattle

I am trying to create a node-link diagram (decision tree) by using `parsnip` and `tidymodels`. What I am performing is building a decision tree model for the StackOverflow dataset using the `tidymodels` package and `rpart` as model engine. The model should predict whether a developer will work remotely (variable `remote`) based on the number of years of programming experience (`years_coded_job`), degree of career satisfaction (`career_satisfaction`), job title "Data Scientist" yes/no (`data_scientist`), and size of the employing company (`company_size_number`).

My pipeline

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
library(rpart.plot)
library(rpart)
library(rattle)

so <- read_rds(here::here("stackoverflow.rds"))

fit <- rpart(remote ~ years_coded_job + career_satisfaction + data_scientist + company_size_number,
             data = so,
             control = rpart.control(minsplit = 20, minbucket = 2))

fancyRpartPlot(fit, sub = "")
```

The plot I obtain

[image: plot]

I want to know whether is this the correct approach for determining the predictors. Since I am not building a model is this the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going [tidymodels](/questions/tagged/tidymodels) and parsnip to fit your model, it's better to use that actual fitted model for any visualizations like this. You can get the underlying engine object from a parsnip model using `$fit`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
library(rattle)
#> Loading required package: bitops
#> Rattle: A free graphical interface for data science with R.
#> Version 5.4.0 Copyright (c) 2006-2020 Togaware Pty Ltd.
#> Type 'rattle()' to shake, rattle, and roll your data.
data(kyphosis, package = "rpart")

tree_fit <- decision_tree(min_n = 20) %>%
  set_engine("rpart") %>%
  set_mode("classification") %>%
  fit(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start,
      data = kyphosis)

fancyRpartPlot(tree_fit$fit, sub = "")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

For some kinds of visualizations, you will need to use [`repair_call()`](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/07/parsnip-0-1-2/#better-call-objects).

Comment: Also, Why is that only 3/4 predictors are showing up in the tree? Is the one named as `data_scientist` has lower information or so the reason it's not chosen? Just asking for an explanatory purpose.

Comment: I couldn't get the results you did using the version I have of the Stack Overflow survey dataset, so I can't say for sure unfortunately.